# uploading images to Cloudinary

Tags: javascript, java, html, node.js, cloudinary

I am trying to upload files directly to Cloudinary using nodejs. I have gotten in to work successfully, but ONLY when I manually set the path of the image I am going to be upload, like so:

```
cloudinary.uploader.upload('./public/css/img/' + data.image)
```

but when I do this:

```
cloudinary.uploader.upload(data.image)
```

it does not work. A sample of my entire function is below. I need it to work like this because when I allow others (not on my local machine) to upload images, it will not work.

```
 // collected image from a user
        const data = {
            image: req.query.image,
          }
          console.log(data)
          // upload image here
          cloudinary.uploader.upload(data.image)
          .then((result) => {
              // response.status(200).send({
              //   message: "success",
              //   result,
              // });
              console.log(result.secure_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

When running the upload call from the root folder it searches for the image in the same folder. You can run the upload from the `img` folder. e.g `cd ./public/css/img/` and then call the upload. or use the full path as you did.

Comment: if I wanted to upload a photo from any folder on my local computer, could I do this?